# Invert a list of (key, values) pairs

Tags: r

I want to invert a named list of `(key,values)` pairs into a named list of `(value,key)` pairs. It's safe to assume that the values are unique across keys but the vectors are of different lengths.

I came up with a solution that uses `purrr::map` and then `purrr::flatten`.

Is there a more elegant solution?

```r
library("tidyverse")

key_values_list <- list(
  a = c("x", "y"),
  b = c("A", "B", "C")
)

myinvert <- function(key, values) {
  setNames(rep_along(values, key), values)
}

value_key_pairs <-
  names(key_values_list) %>%
  map(
    ~ myinvert(., key_values_list[[.]])
  ) %>%
  flatten()
value_key_pairs
#> $x
#> [1] "a"
#> 
#> $y
#> [1] "a"
#> 
#> $A
#> [1] "b"
#> 
#> $B
#> [1] "b"
#> 
#> $C
#> [1] "b"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `stack` with `split` in `base R`

```
with(stack(key_values_list), split(as.character(ind), values))
```

If the order needs to be maintained

```
with(stack(key_values_list), split(as.character(ind),
       factor(values, levels = unique(values))))
```

---

Or with `rep/lengths/unlist`

```
setNames(as.list(rep(names(key_values_list), 
     lengths(key_values_list))), unlist(key_values_list))
```

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about `stack` and `unstack`. I had the suspicion that "invert" is not the right term to search for....

Comment: @dipetkov The `stack/split` assumes that you don't have intersecting values in different keys.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, this does what you want:

```
> library(hash)
> as.list(invert(hash(key_values_list)))
$x
[1] "a"

$y
[1] "a"

$A
[1] "b"

$B
[1] "b"

$C
[1] "b"
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the `hash` package. Which is why I defined an `invert` function in my example. Fixed now, so that it doesn't clash with `hash::invert`.